# Android Maps API key does not work

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I have implemented Google Maps into an existing app and could not get it to work, when I tracked it down the error message was it could not expand the fragment. So I created a new app just for testing purposed and followed the example here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html. It still didn’t work, same error. I have used both debug and release SHA1 fingerprints in the API key. I asked a friend to help and he could not understand either until he registered my SHA1 fingerprint and package name into his API key and substituted his API key with mine and it all started to work.

The only difference is the API key. Anybody got any ideas ?

I'm running Eclipse Kepler SR1, Android 4.0.3 (SDK 11)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that I understand what you do. But since you use Eclipse Kepler, could the problem be that it signs the keystore with SHA256withRSA instead of SHA1withRSA? It was the last problem (of many) that I had to solve until I finally got Map API v2 to run.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088690/generating-signature-with-sha256withrsa-rather-than-sha1withrsa) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54806) for more information.